# Docker Unbound DNS Server: How to launch as service

Tags: linux, docker, dns, server, archlinux

My host system is Arch Linux, and the Docker image is "base/arch" (archlinux) with my own modifications.  Unbound is installed on a committed image, but I don't quite know how to launch the container with the service running since SystemD is not meant to run in Docker.

How do I actually launch the container with Unbound running as a service?

I've gone through some basic tutorials, but most of them cover launching pre-built containers:

[Dockers basic course.](https://training.docker.com/self-paced-training)

[Arch Wiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker)

[Digital Ocean overview.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-docker-ecosystem-an-introduction-to-common-components)

Thanks!

Comment: You should post your Dockerfile so we can see what you've tried. My first suggestion knowing what youve listed above is checkout the ENTRYPOINT entry here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer, I'm assuming that you've installed Unbound by simply installing the `community/unbound` package via *pacman*.

You can inspect the systemd unit files that are installed alongside the package to determine how to actually start the server. Have a look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unbound DNS Resolver
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/cp -f /etc/trusted-key.key /etc/unbound/
PIDFile=/run/unbound.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/unbound -d
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Most important is the `ExecStart` line. This describes the command that systemd uses to actually start the service. According to `unbound`'s help (`unbound -h`), the `-d` switch means *do not fork into the background* (which is a good thing because that's also exactly what you need to start Unbound in a Docker contaier).

The `ExecStartPre` command can be a simple `RUN` step when building the image.

In conclusion, you can translate this into a Dockerfile similar to this:

```
FROM base/arch

# <omitted>

RUN /bin/cp -f /etc/trusted-key.key /etc/unbound/
CMD ["/usr/bin/unbound", "-d"]
```